# creating a table using foreign key of another table error

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have the table uc_users with the following columns:

```
| id | user_name | display_name | password | email |
```

I want to create a second table uc_user_network using the foreign key user_name from the uc_users table.

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE uc_user_network
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
GraphName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
user_name varchar(50),     
networkid varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
FOREIGN KEY (user_name) REFERENCES uc_users(user_name) 
) 

ALTER TABLE uc_users
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users
    FOREIGN KEY (user_name)
    REFERENCES uc_user_network(ID)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_name) REFERENCES uc_users(user_name)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_name` in `uc_user_network` should be the same type as `user_name` in `uc_users` the same as `ID` in `uc_user_network`. So what type should it be? `int` or `varchar(255)` ?

Comment: I don't believe it required to be the exact same type (depending on implementation, of course.) However, the foreign key column(s) must all be *implicitly convertible to the data type of the related primary key column(s).

Comment: Exactly the same type, varchar(50). Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEY (user_name) REFERENCES uc_users(user_name)` is not an error: What is the actual error you're getting?

You won't be able to create a foreign key unless the following conditions are met:

1. The dependency must already exist. In your case, if the table `uc_users` does not yet exist, you can't define a foreign key referring to it.
2. The referenced column(s) must comprise a `primary key` (or, depending on whether or not your SQL implementation supports it, an *alternate key* such as a `unique index`). In your case, if the column `user_name` in the table `uc_users` is not a primary key, you can't reference it as such.
3. Further, if the foreign reference is to a *composite key*, composed of multiple columns, all the key columns must be referenced, in the same order in which they are defined in the primary key.